# Массив из с++ в c# - C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

Имеется функция на с++, которая возвращает одномерный массив. Как получить этот массив в C++/CLI, чтобы потом можно было использовать в C# (имеется в виду, какие типы данных и операторы использовать)?

В CLI массив имеет тип `array<double> ^`, а в С++ `double*`. Как в CLI записать массив из C++? Мой код:

C++:

```
 double *func1(....){
   .........
}
```

C++/CLI:

```
array<double> ^func2(...){
//как здесь обратиться к указателю, который возвращает функция 
//func1, чтобы потом возвратить его из функции func2 для 
//дальнейшего приема в c#
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак. Но вы можете легко сконвертировать вручную.

Например:

```
vector<double> nativeVector;
// ...
auto nItems = nativeVector.size();
array<Double>^ managedArray = gcnew array<Double>(nItems);
for (size_t i = 0; i < nItems; i++)
    managedArray[i] = nativeVector[i];
```

Документация: [How to: Use Arrays in C++/CLI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtbydz1t.aspx).

---

Впрочем, в C++/CLI вы можете пользоваться и нативным массивом, если вам хочется. Конвертировать можно, например, только при передаче в другую часть программы.

---

Если у вас есть сишный массив, вы должны точно знать, сколько в нём элементов. Если вы знаете его длину, используйте её вместо `nItems`, остальной код точно такой же.

Если вы не знаете — упс, с массивом работать невозможно. Сделайте так, чтобы длина стала вам известна.

Comment: C++: 
double *func1(....){
      ......
}

C++/CLI:
array<double> ^func2(...){
    //как здесь обратиться к указателю, который возвращает функция                 //func1, чтобы потом возвратить его из функции func2 для 
//дальнейшего приема в c#
}

Comment: @user206138: Код в комментариях не читается, добавьте его лучше в вопрос. // обновил ответ

Comment: Длину массива я не знаю...

Comment: @user206138: Тогда узнайте как-нибудь. Кроме вас никто её узнать не может. Без этой информации ничего работать не будет, сорри.

Comment: @VladD, а тут никак с pin_ptr?  и типа само все?

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, `pin_ptr` — это оптимизация, чтобы можно было сделать `memcpy`. Тут проблема другого порядка, размер массива неизвестен.

Comment: ага, и его по идее кроме func1 никто не может знать?

Comment: @Grundy: Ага :)

Comment: @VladD, погоди, а `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])`? разве не сработает?

Comment: @Grundy: А откуда ему знать размер? `sizeof` же не волшебник, и вычисляется на этапе компиляции. `sizeof` не знает, что за указателем спрятался массив. Так что получим просто `sizeof(*arr) == sizeof(double)`, т. к. тип `*arr` — `double`.

Comment: интересно :) надо бы проверить, но лень :-D

Comment: @Grundy: http://ideone.com/h8sHM4

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37479/discussion-between-grundy-and-vladd).